# How `tokio::spawn` handles the situation when the future can't be moved?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

The function `tokio::spawn` is defined as follows:

```
pub fn spawn<T>(future: T) -> JoinHandle<T::Output>
```

The `future` does not implement `Copy` trait, so it is moved into the function. But some futures can't be moved because it has pointers pointing to itself. My question is: how does `tokio::spawn` handle this?

Comment: Actually, your question could be more generally: what happens in Rust when you pass some data that points to itself to a function that takes it (ie. that moves it). The short answer is: data in Rust cannot contain pointers to itself. The longer, but more accurate answer is: see [Pin](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html).

Comment: Once they'll start executing they'll not be moved anymore.

Comment: @BlackBeans But the future in `spawn()` is not `Pin`.

Answer (score 1):

Referential data should be created by either:

- `unsafe new() -> Self`: documentation has to justify `unsafe` that the caller must not move it or any internal unsafe pointer operations will have undefined behavior
- a `new() -> Pin<Box<Self>>`: moving is okay, because data is on the heap and will never move.

In the case of a `Future` containing self-referential data, it has to be a `Pin<Box<Fut>>` where `Fut` can be `!Unpin`. I think this is the best way, because you have to move. There might be other structs where your wrapper type is `Unpin` although the inner type is `!Unpin`.

```rust
use std::{
    marker::PhantomPinned,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(CrazyStruct::new("GOOD")).await.unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(unsafe { CrazyStruct::new_unpinned("BAD") }) // invariant violation, by moving here!
        .await
        .unwrap();

    // let cs = CrazyStruct::new("TEST").as_mut().get_mut(); // thanks to `PhantomPinned` that this fails
}

/// Can be safely send between threads. (this comes from pointer are not Send)
unsafe impl Send for CrazyStruct {}

struct CrazyStruct {
    name: &'static str,
    value: u8,

    /// self-referential pointer to `self.value`
    value_ptr: Option<*const u8>,

    _pinned: PhantomPinned,
}

impl CrazyStruct {
    /// Don't move! Contains self-referential data.
    unsafe fn new_unpinned(name: &'static str) -> Self {
        let mut me = CrazyStruct {
            name,
            value: 42,
            value_ptr: None,
            _pinned: PhantomPinned,
        };

        me.value_ptr = Some(&me.value);
        me
    }

    fn new(name: &'static str) -> Pin<Box<Self>> {
        let mut me = Box::pin(CrazyStruct {
            name,
            value: 42,
            value_ptr: None,
            _pinned: PhantomPinned,
        });

        // SAFETY: we don't move
        unsafe {
            me.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().value_ptr = Some(&me.value);
        }

        me
    }
}

impl std::future::Future for CrazyStruct {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        assert!(
            self.value_ptr == Some(&self.value),
            "Did you move '{}'???",
            self.name
        );
        std::task::Poll::Ready(())
    }
}

// thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Did you move 'BAD'???', src/main.rs:66:9
// note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
// thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: JoinError::Panic(Id(10), ...)', src/main.rs:13:10
```

Comment: What is the type of `async` block? Is it `Pin<Box<Future<...>>>`?

Comment: No, the type is actually some anonymous `impl Future<Output=SomeValueType>`. `async/.await` generated code is zero cost, `Box` is not. The compiler will generate some state machine which (may or always do?) contain self-referential data => thus pinning is needed.